# Unloading Mono domains in multithreaded context

Tags: c++, c, mono, appdomain, embedding

I have a multithreaded application that activate multiple Mono domains from native code.
Each domain has it's own thread. 
I use the following code to activate a domain:

```
///Create a new domain.
m_domain = mono_domain_create_appdomain((char*) name.c_str(), NULL);

///Activate the domain.
mono_domain_set(m_domain, 0);

///Register the current thread
mono_thread_attach(m_domain);

///Invoke some code ...
mono_runtime_invoke (m_method, m_objectInstance, NULL, &exception);
```

But when I unload a domain the application crash :

```
mono_domain_unload(m_domain);
```

When I execute the code without threading, the application domains are unloaded correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling the function **mono_assembly_close**, before **mono_domain_unload** :

```
mono_assembly_close(m_assembly);
```

So I removed this call, and created a **critical section** for the unloading code.